# detecting numbers in an html file using python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

I have an HTML file and i would like to parse through it using python 3.2
sample :-

```
<td class="ln">15</td><td class="sf3b2"><code>&nbsp;</code></td>
<td class="ln">15</td><td class="sf3b2"><code>&nbsp;</code></td>
```

The job is to detect the numbers which are not tagged (in this case 15 only) and store them in another text file. I aint being able to decide which html parser to use (lxml,beautiful soup) as I am new to this. Could you please guide me about how to approach this problem.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the html code surrounding the numbers always the same?

Comment: the code surrounding the numbers is always the same.However there are some lines in between which dont have numbers which are to be ignored.All lines having the numbers follow the same format as given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def getPrintUnicode(soup):

    body=''
    if isinstance(soup, unicode):
        soup = soup.replace('&#39;',"'")
        soup = soup.replace('&quot;','"')
        soup = soup.replace('&nbsp;',' ')
        soup = soup.replace('&gt;','>')
        soup = soup.replace('&lt;','<')
        body = body + soup
    else:
        if not soup.contents:
            return ''
        con_list = soup.contents
        for con in con_list:
            body = body + getPrintUnicode(con)
    return body

print getPrintUnicode(BeautifulSoup('<td class="ln">15</td><td class="sf3b2"><code>&nbsp;</code></td>'))
```

You can use this getPrintUnicode() function on the soup of whole page. It will return the complete content. Use exceptions and convert string to integers.
eg.

```
print int(getPrintUnicode(BeautifulSoup('<td class="ln">15</td><td class="sf3b2"><code>&nbsp;</code></td>')))
```

Answer (score 0):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) makes it pretty easy to do this. You can use the [find_all](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method to find the elements and to process them:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
tds = soup.find_all("td", "ln")
for td in tds:
    pass # do something here
```